# how to concatenate option in scala

Tags: scala

What's an elegant/right way in scala to string concatenate an Option so that None renders as an empty string and variables that have a value don't get wrapped in Some("xyz")

```
case class foo(bar: Option[String], bun: Option[String])
println(myFoo.bar+ "," + myFoo.bun)
```

The output I want is for example

```
hello,
```

instead of

`Some(hello),None`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a value from `Option` in a safe way use `getOrElse` and provide a default argument, which would be used in case you `Option` is `None`. In your example it would look like this:

```
case class foo(bar: Option[String], bun: Option[String])
println(myFoo.bar.getOrElse("") + "," + myFoo.bun.getOrElse(""))
```

Then you'll get the required result

Answer (score 11):

One way would be:

```
val a = foo(Some("Hello"), None) 
a.productIterator.collect{ case Some(s) => s }.mkString(",")
```

Another way would be:

```
Seq(bar, bun).flatten.mkString(",")
```

This doesn't do what you asked for, since it doesn't print the comma at the end, but I still suggested it since it might do what you *want*.

Comment: As a case class, we can iterate over its arguments and collect "some" values; for,

val a = foo(Some("Hello"),None) we have that 

a.productIterator.collect{ case Some(s) => s }.mkString(",") and so 
res: String = Hello

Comment: plus 1 for the username.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: to turn an `Option[String]` to a `String`:

```
opt.getOrElse("")
```

or if you prefer the more operator-like method call syntax:

```
opt getOrElse ""
```

then the `getOrElse` can be shortened with the `|` alias provided by [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

opt | ""
```

furthermore, you can let [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) compute that `""` for you; this works thanks to there being a [`Monoid`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monoid.html) instance defined for `String` which defines the empty (or zero) value of `String` to be an empty string:

```
opt.orZero
```

all in all:

```
scala> ("hello".some).orZero + " blabla " + ("world".some).orZero
res9: String = hello blabla world

scala> (none[String]).orZero + " blabla " + ("world".some).orZero
res10: String = " blabla world"

scala> ("hello".some).orZero + " blabla " + (none[String]).orZero
res11: String = "hello blabla "
```

(I'm using the Scalaz `none` and `some` here; with vanilla Scala you'd have to write `None: Option[String]` and `Some("hello"): Option[String` to get the right types)

---

**However**... you'll probably want to avoid that extraneous whitespace, so really in practice you'd use something in the lines of; the above is just for learning/exploration:

```
scala> List("hello".some, Some("blabla"), "world".some).flatten.mkString(" ")
res0: String = hello blabla world

scala> List("hello".some, none[String], "world".some).flatten.mkString(" ")
res1: String = hello world
```

— note how there's always just a single space between words, unlike above.